# C initialized and non initialized array with variable size

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, sizeof, variable-length-array

I have the next two code examples:

```
const char *val = strchr(ch, ' ');
const int diff = (int)(val - ch);

char arr[diff];
```

and

```
const char *val = strchr(ch, ' ');
const int diff = (int)(val - ch);

char arr[diff] = {0};
```

The second one generates the error like

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

It is correct error and I understand why it happens.

I wonder why the first code snippet doesn't generate the error?

**Update:**
Also regarding sizeof(arr) at first snippet gives the size of array, but I thought that sizeof is a compile time operator (?)

Comment: The first snippet doesn’t attempt to initialize the array, so there’s no error to diagnose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case you are trying to initialize a variable length array (because the size of the array is not specified with an integer constant expression; the presence of the qualifier `const` in the declaration of the variable diff does not make it an integer constant expression in the array declaration)

```
char arr[diff] = {0};
```

that is not allowed for variable length arrays.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
> unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length
> array type

You could set all elements of the array to zero the following way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char arr[diff];
memset( arr, 0, diff );
```

As for the operator `sizeof` then for variable length arrays it is calculated at run-time.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer.
> **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is
> evaluated;** otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and
> the result is an integer constant

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is the memory `malloc`-ed in this case?

Comment: @user1570891 No, variable length arrays have automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 4):

This definition:

```
char arr[diff];
```

Creates a **variable length array**.  Such an array has its size determined at runtime.  Because of this, it may not be initialized.